# A word for women's appearance that could easily arouse sympathy from others

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English that describes a woman's appearance that could easily arouse sympathy from others?

something along the line of meek and kittenish?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. How would "kittenish", either in the playful or lively meaning, or the one more specifically used to describe women (2. (of a woman) flirtatious, esp coyly flirtatious), arouse sympathy? Maybe you can explain a bit more. I'm not sure whether it's just me but I'm not understanding clearly.

Comment: We used to say _demure_, but I don't know if that is in the popular lexicon anymore. Apart from that, meek and kittenish do not seem to work together.

Comment: @Cascabel It's interesting, some dictionaries simply say that "demure" is reserved and shy, while others say that it's "affectedly" so, which to me means that she isn't REALLY shy and reserved. Likewise "coy" is usually given with both meanings in two separate definitions, actually shy, and affectedly shy. I'm wondering if the questioner is referring to feeling sympathy for the woman because she is shy/demure/coy.

Comment: @Zebrafish I think the last time I saw the usage was in Mary Stewart's _The Crytal Cave_ (197o), Merlin is describing Ygraine..."...what I would call demure in a young girl", and that definitely would tend to support the idea of a "pretension". But I am relying on memory. Gotta go look it up.

Comment: I'm wondering if the 'others' whose sympathy is aroused includes women and men or if it's just men, and if it's just men, is it all men or say a stereotype Western man from the 1950s? In that case the Stepford wives comes to mind though they have to be good at housework too.

Comment: Hello, Rob. You have the germ of a good question here: you just need to clarify it a bit and show a minimum of research. Right now, I will give you a +1,

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a word in English that describes a woman's appearance that could easily arouse sympathy from others?**

The word **forlorn** immediately springs to mind. However it is not gender explicit.

> **forlorn** adjective (SAD) [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forlorn) literary alone and unhappy; left alone and not cared for:
>
> Example; **She looked a forlorn figure standing at the bus stop**.

Other suggestions are;

> **miserable**; adjective (UNHAPPY) very unhappy: She's miserable living on her own.
>
> **wretched** adjective (BAD QUALITY) unpleasant or of low quality: a wretched childhood

Answer (score 0):

The word **“sympathy”** means different things in different languages. In English, it means something as *compassion, pity, fellow feeling,* so something which make you **unhappy**, while in your native language it is probably something as *liking or fondness,* which make you **happy**.

If it is the case, you may use words as **attractive**, **appealing**, **desirable**, **luscious**, or **alluring**.